# iOS 7 iPad Gmail prevent photo downsizing

Tags: ios, photos, gmail

I'm transferring photos from my camera via the SD adapter. When I attach them from within the Mail app, I'm given the option to choose the photo resolution (Small, Medium, Large, Actual Size) but I don't seem to have this option from within the Gmail app. Am I missing something?

I can see from the Mail app and on the camera that the actual file size it 3.6MB, but the attachment in the Gmail is 1.3MB and is clearly downsampled.  It's frustrating not to be able to send the full resolution attachments!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: do you mean the web gmail?

Comment: No, the native app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Gmail.app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gmail/id422689480?mt=8) does not support this feature and resizes the image automatically.
There is **currently no way** you can prevent this from happening.

You might be able to send feedback to Google about this, but as workaround you can use the native Mail.app provided on a clean install of any iOS version - since you pointed out that's giving you the right options.